# How to parse file for filenames and remove interactively

Tags: linux, bash, unix, xargs

I want to read a file and and parse out filenames and remove them. In my case this means removing everything after the first tab for each line in the file to get the filenames and then calling `rm -i` on the files.

This is what I have so far but it just removes them all without prompting...if I add the `-i` to `xargs rm` it gives me a wall of text without letting me choose `y/n`

```
while IFS=' ' read -r line; do
  #echo ${line%*}
  sed -e 's/\t.*$//' | xargs rm
done < $1
```

Comment: Can u post some sample input and output.... It would be easier for others to understand...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `rm -i` asks for yes/no on stdin. You redirect to the while loop and pipe to `xargs`, both of which will override stdin for `rm -i`.

You can rewrite to avoid `xargs` and also use a different FD for your loop:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -u 3 -r file _ 
do
  rm -i "$file"
done 3< yourfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid `rm -i` and use `xargs -p` for prompting use for each file to be deleted:

```
cut -f1 file | xargs -n1 -p rm
```

Comment: the prompt didn't work. I think it's because of the reason stated by @the other guy

Comment: You are correct that I didn't need the IFS. I tried your solution with the `-u 3` from the accepted answer and that works as well.

Comment: To make it work, I've now modified the answer to use `xargs`

Comment: Thanks, your new solution also works and I learned something new. I was looking for something like this initially and I think other people seeing this will prefer this solution.